# GWT is crashing my browsers on Debug mode, anybody has a solution?

Tags: gwt

Following StockWatcher tutorial,

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/debug.html

When I run the app in debug mode, my Safari or Firefox becomes irresponsive (I can't even switch to them). If I stop the debug mode from Eclipse then everything is back to normal.

I have a MacPro with SnowLeopard, and this is my Java. Google Eclipse plugins are up to date.

```
dvr-2:~ devrim$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04-248-10M3025)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.3-b01-101, mixed mode)
```

Could u advise ?

Comment: I remember once having such an issue with GWT - when running in debug mode, Eclipse would show some popup (that would be only visible if you switched to the main window of Eclipse) that "blocked" the progress of debugging, making it seem like Firefox hang up (no repaints, just a gray window). It's worth checking, though this doesn't seem to be what's happening here (since you are stopping debugging from Eclipse, you'd see such popup).

Comment: Assuming you're using GWT 2.0:

How long are you waiting? It's normal for the browser to appear to freeze while the debugger is connecting to it. What does the debug window in Eclipse say? Does it show the browser connecting?

Comment: Here is how it goes, I start the debug mode, go to browser, add the first variable (goes very slow) hit enter, and go to eclipse and see those breakpoints and their assigned variables. But I can never switch back to browser - it's totally gone. both FF and safari. same story.

Comment: Ummm, if you hit a stop at a breakpoint, you need to resume the application (F8), otherwise FF will appear blocked while waiting for the code to resume execution.

Comment: Updating to the latest GAE SDK and GWT version solved it. My browsers weren't only appearing blocked, it was crashing: http://u.kodingen.com/zgO5Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest GAE SDK and GWT version solved it. My browsers weren't only appearing blocked, it was crashing: u.kodingen.com/zgO5Y